Adding new array in state doesn't trigger re-render (React)
I'm trying to download objects, store them in an array and save a copy of that array in state. I'm also trying to display content from the state array.
Here's the component with the irrelevant parts excluded:
const UpdateProfile = () => {

  const [userFiles, setUserFiles] = useState<any>([])

  async function downloadFiles() {
    
    try {
      let newFileList: any = []
      const downloadedFiles = await listAll(storageRef)
      const downloadedFilesCopy = [...downloadedFiles.items]
      downloadedFilesCopy.forEach(async (file: any) => {
        let downloadedFileMetadata: any = await downloadMetadata(file)
        downloadedFileMetadata.url = await findDownloadURL(file)
        newFileList.push(downloadedFileMetadata)
      
      })
      console.log(newFileList)
      console.log(userFiles)
      setUserFiles((prev: any) => [...prev, ...newFileList])
      console.log(userFiles)
    } catch(e) {
      alert(e)
    }
  }

  async function downloadMetadata(item: StorageReference) {
    const fileRef = ref(storage, item.toString())
    try {
      const metadata = await getMetadata(fileRef)
      return metadata

    } catch(e) {
      alert(e)
    }

  }

  async function findDownloadURL(item: StorageReference) {
    const fileRef = ref(storage, item.toString())
    try {
      const url = await getDownloadURL(fileRef)
      return url

    } catch(e) {
      alert(e)
    } 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProfileDetails()
    downloadFiles()

  }, [])
  
  return (
    <Container id="update-page-container">
        {userFiles.map((file: any) => <p>File here</p>)}
    </Container>
  )
}



The state is updated correctly in the background but there is no re-render, even though calling setUserFiles with a new array each time (as far as I can tell).
Can anyone help me get React to re-render because I'm pulling my hair out.
Tried multiple ways to set state, e.g.
      setUserFiles(newFileList)
      setUserFiles([...newFileList])



you can look at this question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top

Whats happening is that due to the asynchronous nature of your code (the download/for loop being async and the state update also being async, the setUserFiles might not be happening after the files have been downloaded. Specifically downloadedFilesCopy.forEach(async (file: any) ...
So what's probably happening is

you are triggering the forloop and the async function calls
The setUserFiles update gets called, but files aren't done downloading.
Then the files finish downloading, but setUserFiles has already executed with the old file list.

I believe you can await Promise.all on the download portion of your code to wait for all files to finish downloading before updating the state variable.
Something like
const filesWithMetadata = await Promise.all(
    downloadedFilesCopy.map(async (file: any) => {
        const downloadedFileMetadata: any = await downloadMetadata(file);
        downloadedFileMetadata.url = await findDownloadURL(file);
          return downloadedFileMetadata;
        })
      );

setUserFiles(filesWithMetadata)


Thanks for taking the time to feedback on this. I'll try this solution and report back

Functions which are used in a useEffect, should be declared within useEffect. So, the getProfileDetails should be inside in useEffect.
  useEffect(() => {
    async function downloadFiles() {
      // ...
      const newFileList = downloadedFilesCopy.map(async (file: any) => {
        let downloadedFileMetadata: any = await downloadMetadata(file)
        downloadedFileMetadata.url = await findDownloadURL(file) 
        return downloadedFileMetadata
      })
      setUserFiles((prev: any) => ([...prev, ...newFileList]))
      // ...
    }

    downloadFiles()
  }, [])

Additionally, promises in Array.forEach don't work as expected, may cause buggy results, instead, better use Array.map.

I didn't know that - I'll update my code accordingly. Thanks for your help!
